# Is IIS hosted service always UP?

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

How I can be sure that my WCF service hosted on IIS 7.5 is always up?  Is there any setting or extra piece of code I need to write?

Answer (score 1):

Since your WCF service is hosted in IIS, it is just another web application that can be benefited from the Auto-start feature of IIS 7.5. ScottGu explained about that in this post:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series